# How can i do the sumation of time in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this :

[image]

And in this table you can see the last column totalloginFinal, I want to do the sum of all time, its will be about 84 hours,

I am trying with addtime and sum function but not getting proper result.

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this variant -

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(totalloginFinal))) FROM table_name;
```

From the reference - *The SUM() and AVG() aggregate functions do not work with temporal values. (They convert the values to numbers, which loses the part after the first non-numeric character.) To work around this problem, you can convert to numeric units, perform the aggregate operation, and convert back to a temporal value.*

[GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

try convert it to [second](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_second) and then sum the seconds and convert it back from second to [time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time)

like :

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(SECOND(totalloginFinal))) as Total from mytable
```